# Ubuntu 16.04 setting static IP not working

Tags: 16.04, static-ip

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu server on a virtual machine hosted on a windows OS. When I set it to the default DHCP the internet works fine. When I attempt to set up a static IP I get TX but no RX.

The following is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.1.150
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Most of the solutions I've seen to similar problems have to do with not having a DNS server named but I do have one, so I'm not sure what else to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pelase add more details such as the virtualization environment, type of networking adn host network details.

Comment: I'm using Oracle VM Virtualbox and using a NAT network interface

Comment: To be clear also I'm a TOTAL newbie with this stuff.

Comment: Did you create a 192.168.1.0/24 virtual network with Virtualbox and assign the host the ip 192.168.1.1? Can you ping / access the host?

Comment: So I tried a completely different approach. Everywhere I saw on the internet was telling me to to 192.168.x.x addresses. I rebooted my server and set it back to DHCP, checked my ifconfig and noticed my address was 10.0.x.x and my gateway was 10.0.x.x with netmask 255.255.255.0...So I changed my settings to basically match what DHCP had given me and then just set it to static instead and it works now! Is this correct at all? Again I'm really sorry but I'm a total noob at this.

Comment: Yes, it completely make sense now. It looked to me as if you were trying to setup bridged networking because `192.168.1.1` is often the default address of hoe routers. Please create an answer and later accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve my own problem. Basically everywhere on the internet I was looking was telling me to use an address of 192.168.x.x

I reset my network to DHCP and ran ifconfig to find out the DHCP address was 10.0.x.x

So I went back to my network and input the following

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 10.0.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.z.z
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

And set the .x.x to match what I was initially given by DHCP, and it worked. Apparently I was trying to set the ip address to my home routers IP instead of the network that my VM was giving to me.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.